# Searching for open source Software for motor driver Simulation (PUC inverter)

Tags: simulation, inverter

I am trying to simulate **the Five Phase Five Level PUC Inverters** as you can see below (from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330170709_Performance_of_Five_Phase_PUC_Inverter_Fed_Five_Phase_Induction_Motor_Drive_Under_Different_Triangular_Carrier_PWM_Schemes)):

[image]

So as I don't have Matlab licence for this simulation I am trying for others alternative to do this simulation.

I have googled these terms:

1. [site:github.com python   5 phase motor inverter  simulation](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%20python%20%20%205%20phase%20motor%20inverter%20%20simulation&bih=986&biw=2058&hl=fa&sxsrf=ALeKk03hHBGh44bVjbDdA5BdyHNSdfajqw%3A1619245766383&ei=xrqDYPzuFoqjgQbC4ZOQBA&oq=site%3Agithub.com%20python%20%20%205%20phase%20motor%20inverter%20%20simulation&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQlR5Y3UxguE5oB3ACeACAAdMCiAHVHZIBBjItMTQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj86dXFoJbwAhWKUcAKHcLwBEIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)
2. [open source motor driver simulator matlab alternative](https://www.google.com/search?q=opensource%20motor%20dirver%20simulator%20matlab%20alternative&oq=opensource%20motor%20dirver%20simulator%20matlab%20alternative&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.11207j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

And found some results like [gym electric motor](https://github.com/upb-lea/gym-electric-motor) Project with Python language (Ref [1](https://colab.research.google.com/github/upb-lea/gym-electric-motor/blob/master/examples/environment_features/GEM_cookbook.ipynb),[2](https://colab.research.google.com/github/upb-lea/gym-electric-motor/blob/master/examples/model_predictive_controllers/pmsm_mpc_dq_current_control.ipynb)) :

[image]

If Possible, I like to Have your comment for finding some Open source Software With GUI Motor Driver Simulator like Matlab Motor simulation which is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAA3L8bLAyE).

Thanks.

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, If this question is not **off topic**,I will wait for two days and if not get answer here, I will ask there. **Otherwise**, it would be better to bookmark this question as off topic to do it faster.